# Git push from local repo to origin

Tags: git

I need to ask this question but may be its way simple , but i tried searching for answer and the google results are all pointing me to an answer which is not working.

My current setup is

```
git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master

git branch
* m1
  master
  remote
```

i created m1 as a repo using got checkout -br m1

I am making all my changes in the m1 local branch rather than i master and hence i made some change in my pom.xml and comiited it as shown below.

```
 git log --graph --stat origin/master..
* commit c44d62aecef8bef168cc60303ef36dab47117428
  Author: Yatin
  Date:   Wed Apr 10 13:38:44 2013 -0700

      fixing error in pom.xml

   map_reduce/pom.xml |   14 ++++++--------
   1 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
```

I want to push this change which i have made in the m1 local repo to origin
and i have tried this

```
git push origin m1
```

this basically creates a new remote repo called m1. I dont want to create a remote repo called m1 but just push the changes in m1 to origin. I am missing some fundamental concpet but not sure what it is. can someone tell me how can it be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which branch you want remotely, so it assumed origin/m1.

Try

```
git push origin m1:master
```

The syntax is

```
git push remote local_branch:remote_branch
```

Comment: Almost the same as what I was thinking as an answer. I just got used to merging my local branches to master before pushing them.

Comment: Well this doesnt work and gives me error as shown below
------
git push origin/master m1
fatal: 'origin/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: @eis I had the same question, thanks, but I have an additional question: How to delete the m1 that was created on the origin?

Comment: @user2441441 standard `git push origin --delete m1` should do it